# Draw a Custom View background

Tags: cocoa

could you guys give me some hints about how to draw in a Custom View?

Comment: A few choice words when searching the documentation gives all sorts of promising links. You should try searching the docs before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), read the [View Programming Guide's drawing section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW22),  create an NSView subclass of your own, and start playing with -drawRect:. Seriously, though, read the guides. Front to back.